# Redshift : Change Server Configurations or Keep changes all the sessions

Tags: amazon-redshift

This time may I ask if there is anyway to change server configuration without re-creation of the Redshift instance..?

I understand we can change the server configuration by set command in only current session, but we'd like to keep them in all user sessions, especailly for BI sessions.

-- Redshift Server Configurations

```
name                           current_setting     new_setting
-------------------------------------------------------------------
datestyle                       SQL, YMD          ISO, YMD
timezone                           utc            Asia/Tokyo
describe_field_name_in_uppercase   off            on
```

If it's impossible to change default setting without re-creation, I'm just wondering Redshift can have any alternative way like SQL Server's login trigger, which can allow to start user session with some special procedure(s) as follows;

```
-- ex. SQL Server Logon Trigger sample

CREATE TRIGGER [open_key_trigger_test_xxxx]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
begin try
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'XXXX'
begin
-- certificate key open for encode/decode until the session end.
exec TEST_DWH.dbo.OpenKeys;   
end
end try
begin catch
print ERROR_Message()
rollback;
end catch
END;
```

We'd like to execute set command 'set datestyle to 'ISO, YMD'' at the beginning of the each user session, if possible.

Or any recommendable way whould be so much appreciated.

Bset Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating the cluster is not necessary. If you want to change these settings for the *entire cluster* and not just a session then you can do this by [modifying the cluster Parameter Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Modifying_the_default_settings.html) in the AWS Console (or using the Redshift API if that's more your thing).

Just add or modify the required parameters and the reboot the cluster, then the new settings will take effect.

Note that for the **timezone** setting, this can't be set as part of the Parameter Group as the cluster timezone is always UTC. However you can [set a default timezone for each database user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_timezone_config.html), to do this you need to use the ALTER USER.. SET TIMEZONE.. syntax instead.

Comment: I really appreciated all of your helpful advice, Nathan !!  I'm glad to know we can make it only console set and reboot the cluster. And for timezone parameter, which only we can configure by session, first I thought to set at the initial string on ODBC or BI setting, but your idea is more brilliant, to set the database user as default timezone. Thank you so much!!